# How to pass value in onPress method of TouchableOpacity without arrow and without bind function - **JSX props should not use arrow functions**

Tags: typescript, react-native, jsx, arrow-functions

I have a TouchableOpacity in my view in React Native project and that has onPress method. I dont want to use arrow function and bind function in onPress method, as this create a new function every time. I want to pass parameter in onPress method. Below is the code for the same -

```
<TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.9}
        style={styles.touchOfferItem}
        onPress={() => this.gotoOfferDetail(item)}
        accessibilityLabel={`Test`}
        testID={'Test'}
        accessible={false}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

```
gotoOfferDetail (offerData:IOfferDetailItem) {
    console.log(offerData.title)
  }
```

I dont want to use onPress in arrow function as it give me **JSX props should not use arrow functions**. Could anyone assist us with this situation and offer any solutions?

Any help is really appreciated.

I have search multiple things but did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a function which returns another function like this:

```js
gotoOfferDetail (offerData: IOfferDetailItem) {
    return () => console.log(offerData.title)
}
```

```js
<TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.9}
        style={styles.touchOfferItem}
        onPress={this.gotoOfferDetail(item)}
        accessibilityLabel={`Test`}
        testID={'Test'}
        accessible={false}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, This works fine for TouchableOpacity. What if I use FlatList? <FlatList
          data={
            this.state.activeTab === 'current'
              ? this.state.activeTabResult
              : this.state.pastTabResult
          }
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item:IJobData) => item.jobId.toString()}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.headerDataJobs}
          ListFooterComponent={this.footerDataJobs}
        /> keyExtractor create JSX error 
Kirill Novikov

Comment: @IlaNautiyal for FlatList you just need to pass `renderItem` function. In your case error provably related to `item.jobId.toString()` where `jobId` is empty. Btw can you please mark initial question as answered.